# jquery why is body click not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does following code not go to a new page?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document.body).click(function(){
        window.location.href="who.html" ;
    });
});
```

I don't see any direct mistakes, I've tried with $(body) $('body') and $('#body') and whenever i click on the body of my page I'm not going to the next page.

Comment: Are you getting any warnings in the console? Are you sure the ready function is firing? Did you include this code *after* loading jQuery?

Comment: I copied your code to the console, clicked the body on this page and got redirected to `who.html` (which redirects back here for some reason).

Comment: I've added it after the loading of jquery and I got a console message telling me that the ready function was getting initialized

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NjZ7h/) out, as you can see if you click on "test" it works very well, otherwise it doesn't work. Why? Because `body` is all which has some content inside it, not the whole page(so if body is empty `click` event will never be triggered). If you want the whole page to be redirected on click, you have to bind `$(document)`.

```
$(document).click(function() {
    window.location.href = "who.html";
});
```

Comment: thank you this fixed it for me, I didn't know that you had to bind it to document, thanks for the quick reply!!!

Comment: Note for people who found this on google but are looking for a vanilla JS solution: An equivalent code snippet would be `document.addEventListener("click", click);` (had the same issue with `body.addEventListener()`)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).click(function(){
        console.log('Document is clicked!');
        window.location.href="who.html" ;
    });
});
```